# Access parent class instance variable from child class function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a parent class.

header file(Parent.h):

```
@interface Parent
@end
```

implementation file (Parent.m):

```
@interface Parent {
    // I defined a instance vaiable 'name'
    NSString *name;
    // another custom type instance variable
    School *mySchool;
}
@end

@implementation Parent
...
@end
```

Then, I have a `Child` class which **inherits** `Parent`.

header (Child.h):

```
@interface Child : Parent
-(void)doSomething;
@end
```

implementation file (Child.m):

```
@implementation Child
-(void)doSomething{
 // Here, how can I access the instance variable 'name' defined in Parent class?
 // I mean how to use the 'name' instance, not only get its value.
 // for example: call writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error: on 'name' here


  // tried to access mySchool defined in parent class
  // Property 'mySchool' not found on object of type 'Parent'
  School *school = [self valueForKey:@"mySchool"];
}
@end
```

How can I access instance variable defined in parent class from child class function?

**==== Clarification ===**

I mean how to use the 'name' instance, not only get its value.
for example: call [writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:) on 'name' here

Comment: You may use a `Parent+Private.h` file to add properties, since I guess that you don't want another object access `name` of a `Parent` object.

Comment: Why not define the variable in Parent.h ? Then you can access using `self->name`.

Comment: you can directly access with self.name in child class if declared in h file

Comment: @MikeAlter You are thinking of properties, not instance variables.

Comment: @Droppy i am actually thinking of properties ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using key-value coding.

Setting:

```
[self setValue:@"Hello" forKey:@"name"];
```

Reading:

```
NSString* name = [self valueForKey:@"name"];
[name writeToFile:@"Filename"
       atomically:YES
         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            error:nil];
```

Comment: Doesn't that require setter/getter methods?

Comment: Yeah just checked the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html); it requires an accessor *or* instance variable.

Comment: I mean how to call function on `name`, please see my update. I don't mean only to read its value

Comment: @Leem.fin This answer tells you that!  Get the `NSString*` and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, does this apply to accessing any type of object from parent class? For example, I might have custom type `School` in Parent class & I want to access it from Child class function.

Comment: @Leem.fin Yes, it does. Red the docs provided by Droppy in his comment above

Comment: WHEN do you get the error? During compilation or runtime?

Comment: This is very weird that you get the error. Your code is absolutely valid. It should compile and run without any problems

Comment: during compilation phase.

Comment: It's impossible. that line must compile. This error means that you'e trying to access it like self.mySchool somewhere

Comment: Ok , I have to import School in my Child class. Could you please add this also to your answer, then, I can accept it

Comment: Potentially unsafe solution. Guess what will happen when variable `name` will stop exists.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, I understand your point. Do you have a better solution? Seriously, I really want to have a good solution.

Comment: @Leem.fin, create private header. Actually I suggest don't use ivars, use properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended now to user ivars in code and declare ivars in public header, but if you really-really need that, then you can use this old-style code:

```
//Parent.h
@interface Parent: NSObject {

@protected
    NSString *_name;
    School *_mySchool;
}
@end

//Parent.m
@implementation Parent
...
@end

//Child.h
@interface Child : Parent
-(void)doSomething;
@end

//Child.m
@implementation Child
-(void)doSomething{
  School *school = self->_mySchool;
  NSString *name = self->_name;
}
@end
```

Comment: you can omit @protected. It is the default access level